# How to know the actual height of an iframe's content?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, shadow-dom

I have this code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script>
        function resizeiframe() {
            var Lyrics = document.getElementById("Lyrics");

            Lyrics.height = Lyrics.contentWindow.document.documentElement.scrollHeight;
        }

    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <iframe id="Lyrics" src="X-Raym_Lyrics.html" scrolling="auto" title="Lyrics" width="100%"></iframe>
    </br>
    <button type="button" id="resizeiframebutton" onclick="resizeiframe()" title="Resize">Resize</button>
</body>

</html>
```

When i inspect the tag body (or html tag doesnt matter is an example) from X-Raym_Lyrics.html in chrome opened outof iframe i see that my script arent able to pickup a real value of height of the content to the height of iframe.
[image: Text]

Is there a way to pickup the real height of the web page.

Comment: _"Script access to a frame's content is subject to the same-origin policy. Scripts cannot access most properties in other window objects if the script was loaded from a different origin, including scripts inside a frame accessing the frame's parent. Cross-origin communication can be achieved using Window.postMessage()."_ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#scripting

Comment: @DiegoD I know. But my .html are mobile and desktop ready, and i want to sandbox this and another file(because there is an java API that brick and to make the work easy i prefer use an iframe) and mix the two html in one view. I can use a fixed width of 100%, but i need but not an height and need specifically the real height.

Comment: my comment was aimed at understand if you were embedding a cross-origin source. I'm not sure you told me between the lines. Maybe yes but I'm not still sure so I'll just ask. Is the page you are embedding coming from the same hostname? if yes, I think your approach maybe already worked. If no, I think you have no choice.. unless reverse proxing the content to make it pass through the same domain.

Comment: @DiegoD Yes all the files are in the same server, i can access both with localhost:8080/file1.html and localhost:8080/file2.html as example dir. But not in the same dir or subdir. One is in the dir C:\folder1\file2.html and another in dir C:\folder2\file1.html (example) and is to be hosted in that directory in production too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following JavaScript code to get the actual height of the iframe content:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('yourIframeID');
var iframeDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
var height =iframeDoc.body.scrollHeight;
```

Some resources:

1. HTML DOM contentDocument Property: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_frame_contentdocument.asp
2. HTML DOM contentWindow Property: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_frame_contentwindow.asp
3. HTML DOM scrollHeight Property: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_scrollheight.asp

Don't forget the vote :)

Comment: `SecurityError: Permission denied to access property "document" on cross-origin object` .. and from the very first page linked: _"Because of security reasons, the contents of a document can be accessed from another document only if the two documents are located in the same domain."_

Comment: With cross-origin you _can_ go the long way around and pass the information to a back-end server, your main document then has to read. Still requires access to the IFRAME code.

Comment: I cant give a good vote because it does the same result.

Comment: @DiegoD Can you explain me the  windows.postmessage aproach.
Im trying that example to understand but is not working to me. Maybe i dont know where to put the last script.

Comment: @AbdallahAyed Im conclused that was a bug of the content page.